# How to show images from a url

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to manipulate images using `cv2`. The images are in url form. When I try to run a `cv2.imshow()` function, I get the following error:

```
error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function cv::imshow
```

Here is some sample code:

```
im = cv2.imread('https://mp-media.reebonz.com/images/p-9a/reebonz-31-phillip-
lim--ladies-bag-31-phillip-lim-1-9ad505f2-03fa-41c1-97dd-
63c6695f89fa.jpg;mode=pad;bgcolor=fff;404=404.jpg')
cv2.imshow('image', im)
```

How would I get the images to show? Would I have to download each image locally before manipulating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from skimage import io

url_path = "URL/path"    

image = io.imread(url_path)
```

It will still create a temporary file for processing the image

for detail **[imread()](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#imread)**

using PIL and urllib

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image
import urllib

Image.open(StringIO(urllib.urlopen(url).read()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the image to an Numpy Array and then read it into OpenCV format. For that you can simply write a Method:

```
 def url_to_image(url):
        resp = urllib.urlopen(url)
        image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
        image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

        return image
```

Then in your Main Code you can call the Method and show the image like this:

```
image = url_to_image(url)
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
```

Let me know if it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try VideoCapture?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('URL/To/Your.jpg')

# Read frame (read again if source changes like updated jpegs from a webcam)
ret, frame = cap.read()

cv2.imshow('image', frame)

cv2.waitKey(0)

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Google says something similar:
http://answers.opencv.org/question/16385/cv2imread-a-url/